# Representing circle numbers as unsigned long integers

Tags: int, geometry, long-integer, operations

I am doing a project where I am doing a lot of computations on the circle S^1, that is, the interval [0,1) with all operations mod 1. It struck me that the double number representation is quite clunky for this purpose, as it contains quite a lot of redudant information, such as the sign, possibility of exponents larger that 0 etc.

My idea is to instead use unsigned long integers. Since every number (in binary) in [0,1) is of the form 0.101001... I only need to store the digits after the decimal point. Thus, a long *n* (in binary) would represent the number 0.*n*.

My question is how to effectivly implement standard operations in this system. Addition and subtraction is simply done as usual mod 2^64. However, multilication and division seems a bit trickier. And what about elementary functions? Perhaps this has already been implemented?

Thankful for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Would [libfixmath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libfixmath) do the trick?